# How to run concurrently but exit 1 if any fails?

Tags: bash

I have the following sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & \
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & \
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & \
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & \
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & \
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here]
```

This works partially because it does run the deploy commands concurrently but I must return an appropriate exit code if any of the deployments' exit code is bigger than 0.

It there any way to accomplish this with just bash? If possible, without using any tmp files, just variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why you want the *biggest* exit code; without further information, I would assume you simply want to return a non-zero exit code if *any* of the other processes has a non-zero exit code.

```
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & pids+=($!)
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & pids+=($!)
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & pids+=($!)
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & pids+=($!)
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & pids+=($!)
ecs deploy [some not relevant stuff here] & pids+=($!)

rv=0
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  wait "$pid" || rv=1
done
exit "$rv"
```

Comment: Yes I don't need the biggest.. Just need to know about non-zero ones.

Answer (score 1):

First off for managing subprocesses I would recommend switching to python as it has a few modules that just do it better than anything you can ever write with bash, that being said.

Lots of OK answers here but this is how I would do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 4; /bin/false &
pids+=("$!")
sleep 5 &
pids+=("$!")
sleep 5 &
pids+=("$!")
sleep 5 &
pids+=("$!")
sleep 5 &
pids+=("$!")

declare -A -g exit_tracker=()

rc=0
for pid in ${pids[@]}; do
    wait $pid
    if (( $? == 1 )); then
        exit_tracker[$pid]="FAIL"
    else
        exit_tracker[$pid]="SUCCESS"
    fi
done

for key in ${!exit_tracker[@]}; do
    printf "%s\n" "$key PID STATUS: ${exit_tracker[$key]}"
done
```

**IF YOU WANT TO GET EVEN CRAZIER!** You can name each return code with an associative array and find out specifically which pid failed. You can supplement your own names where you see sleep_fail, sleep_pass_1 etc...

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A -g pid_names=()

sleep 4; /bin/false &
pid_names["sleep_fail"]="$!"
sleep 5 &
pid_names["sleep_pass_1"]="$!"
sleep 5 &
pid_names["sleep_pass_2"]="$!"
sleep 5 &
pid_names["sleep_pass_3"]="$!"
sleep 5 &
pid_names["sleep_pass_4"]="$!"

declare -A -g exit_tracker=()

rc=0
for pid in ${!pid_names[@]}; do
    wait ${pid_names[$pid]}
    if (( $? == 1 )); then
        exit_tracker[$pid]="FAIL"
    else
        exit_tracker[$pid]="SUCCESS"
    fi
done

for key in ${!exit_tracker[@]}; do
    printf "%s\n" "$key PID STATUS: ${exit_tracker[$key]}"
done
```

Output from the above would look like this:

```
dumbledore@ansible1a [OPS]:~ > bash test.sh
sleep_fail PID STATUS: FAIL
sleep_pass_4 PID STATUS: SUCCESS
sleep_pass_2 PID STATUS: SUCCESS
sleep_pass_3 PID STATUS: SUCCESS
sleep_pass_1 PID STATUS: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thank you. I selected the other answer because it's the simplest one. I really try to avoid using bash, even more when there's complex stuff going on. I usually would pick node for that kind of stuff. I didn't use node for this particular case because it's a python project.

Comment: Sure thing! Just giving you options :). If it comes down to needing to know which specific command returned an exit of nonzero this answer will easily do that for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
# note normal single quotes in following line
CMD='curl -I shoudfail.com'

# run the command, and log it IF IT FAILS
( $CMD || echo $CMD >> tmpout ) &

# rinse, lather, repeat
CMD='curl -I somecmdthatwillfail.com'

# run the command, and log it IF IT FAILS
( $CMD || echo $CMD >> tmpout ) &

...

while [ ! -z `jobs` ]  
do
   sleep 5
done
```

If you use readline to populate CMD rather than literals in the code, then you can use the output of one iteration as the input for the next.

Comment: I think `wait` does the same as your while loop, am I wrong? Could you get  it to work without `cat`ting to a file?  BTW, I'm not interested in the cmd output, just the exit code.

Comment: Potentially multiple things will fail - presumably you want to be able differentiate between the things which worked and those which didn't - in the example above, I only log the things which failed. Adding the return code to the output is **very** trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This array will store process ID's of background processes
declare -a pid

# Run curl and save add its pid to array
curl -I shoudfail.com; echo $? >> tmpout &
pid+=( $! )

# Run another curl and save add its pid to array
curl -I somecmdthatwillfail.com a; echo $? >> tmpout & \
pid+=( $! )

# Run a third curl and save add its pid to array
curl -I google.com; echo $? >> tmpout;
pid+=( $! )

# Wait for all background processes to stop
wait

# Loop through array of pids
for proc in "${pid[@]}"; do
    # Get return value of process from wait
    wait "$proc"
    retval=$?

    # Replace maxret if the return value is larger
    [ "$retval" -gt "$maxret" ] && maxret="$retval"

done

echo "$maxret"
```